# can not make a table in sqlite3 by Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

i have made a database in terminal by this command:

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

then i tried to make a table by using these codes:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
db1.setDatabaseName("test.db");
bool k=db1.open();

QSqlQuery q(db1);
q.prepare("CREATE TABLE by_code(id INT)");
q.exec();
qDebug()<<"isOpen: "<<k<<" Error:"<<q.lastError();
```

the output is :

```
isOpen: true  Error: QSqlError(-1, "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
```

whats problem and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 5):

Qt tried to get the result of the query, but a `CREATE TABLE` statement does not return a result.

This is not considered an actual error.
To check whether the query succeeded, check the return value of the `exec` function.